# Several questions about Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and have some questions:

1. What tutorials are available for the complete beginner to RoR?
2. How to get RoR up and running on Mac OS X (10.5.8) - where and how to install?
3. Can RoR work with an Oracle 10g backend and if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For rails, there is this new site put up by the evangelism team http://railstutorial.org/

The problem with rails is because it moves very fast, books tend to go out of date very quickly. Aparently, railstutorial is supposed to stay up to date with the current stable version (starting with 3.0)

I am assuming you don't know ruby either. Personally, I came for rails, but stayed for ruby. It is an incredibly interesting language you can go very deep with. I would highly recommend [The Well Grounded Rubyist](http://www.manning.com/black2/) by David Black, I bought loads of books starting out, but that one was by far the best for someone who doesn't already know ruby. While the why book is awesome for many reasons, the david black book will get you further, faster.

Haven't done rails on oracle before, but [this](http://blog.rayapps.com/2010/06/21/oracle-enhanced-adapter-1-3-0-is-rails-3-compatible/) looks fairly up to date.

As for setting up your stack on OSX, I would recommend checking out [homebrew](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/), as well as the tutorial links you get from other answers.

Comment: Hi @Matt and others - thanks for the info. @Matt, you are correct, I am a complete newbie to both "Ruby" and "Rails" and it sounds like the book by David Black could be a goer for where I am at and where I would like to get to. If you also know of any decent podcasts/YouTubes! etc, pls pass on as well. Thanks.

Comment: the only podcast i listen to every episode is the changelog. Not rails specific, but the two hosts are rails guys, so there is a high percentage of ruby/javascript on the show

Answer (score 3):

It is important that you understand Ruby before trying to use RoR. Rails is just a framework that works on top of Ruby. If you want an interesting take on learning Ruby, check out [Why's Poignant Guide to Ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/book/chapter-1.html). There's also [Try Ruby!](http://tryruby.org/) which is an interactive tutorial that lets you code in your browser as you go through it.

Once you are comfortable with Ruby, [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) has a series of (currently 233) screencasts dealing about various aspects of Rails. There are also the [official Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) which cover a variety of topics.

I've never tried it before myself, but the Oracle manual has a section on [Ruby on Rails](http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Using+Oracle+and+Ruby+on+Rails).

Comment: Up voted for recommending the most poignant technical manual existence.

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle support, You definitely want to check out [oracle adapter](http://github.com/rsim) made by Raimonds.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Ruby on Rails tutorials](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ruby+on+rails+tutorial)
2. [Installing (with ruby gems)](http://rubyonrails.org/download)
3. No idea

Answer (score 0):

To get Rails up and running on OS X it's fairly simple. Just update RubyGems by opening terminal and entering "sudo gem update --system". Once that's completed you should run a similar command to update the rest of the RubyGems "sudo gem update" and that should get you up and running.

There is a one-click installer for Ruby 1.8.7 if RubyGems requires it which is likely. http://rubyosx.rubyforge.org/. I wouldn't go for Ruby 1.9 just yet as a number of Gems don't support it.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask one question in one question.

Your first two questions are being asked over and over again. If you are not aware, there are quite many good searching engines, perhaps you could try [google](http://www.google.com), or even you could search SO.

Your third question, take a look [here](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/database-support/oracle) (I just put `rails oracle 10g` in google and it was 4th link!)

Comment: Appreciate your response @klew but sometimes how do I know whether the sites I find through Google are the best ones to use as an initial reference. Sometimes I find people who know Ruby and Rails or any other technology, can point you in the right direction without barking up the wrong tree. People I find are very helpful like that. I hope this makes sense. As an example, @Matt above has already pointed me to a Ruby book to start off with.

Comment: @tonsils: I understand your point, but even here on SO there are many questions like yours, just put 'learining rails' in search.